# Drop down input different for Chrome and Firefox

Tags: forms, css

I am creating a form. The forms drop down input **Date of birth** shows smaller in Firefox while works perfectly fine in Chrome. Please help me out to fix it up in Firefox. Here is what I have done,
Find fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EztZf/).

Code,

```
.appformddl
{

margin: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
width: 140px;
padding: 0px 0px;
border: 1;
height:18px;
}
```

Comment: Works fine in Fx 17.0.1. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @KevinBoucher: The input area is smaller as compared to other input areas. Works fine for me in Chrome. I am using Firefox 10.0

Comment: Smaller how? Not as wide, not as tall? (They look the same to me.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that setting font-size on option is respected under Firefox, but not under Chrome. Try setting the desired font-size *only* on the select elements, not globally on the option elements.